# Add new tab on product detail page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I want to add an extra tab on product detail page just like review tab, It will  look like a product question tab. How can I do this?

My block file:

```
namespace Example\ProductQuestion\Block;

use Example\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Question extends Template
{
    private $_productCollectionFactory;

    public  function __construct (
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setOrder('created_at')
            ->setPageSize(5);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way to edit product tabs would be to use the following extension - https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-product-tabs.html

Comment: Use [this extension](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-custom-product-tabs-extension.html) for adding custom tabs and all the customization features.

Answer (score 38):

In Magento 2 to apply the new tab in product detail page is very easy task. Use below steps and check it out. It will display the tab in your theme.

1. Create file `catalog_product_view.xml` in the app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/layout

In the file write the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="deliveryinfo.tab" as="deliveryinfo" template="product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Question</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. create the file `delivery_info.phtml` in the path app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.

In the file you can write any content or you can call the static block like this

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('delivery_info')->toHtml(); ?>
```

3. `delivery_info` block we have to create in admin side `Content/Block`.

Now check in the Detail page.

Comment: thank you for help me but after all your step, it seem nothing changes in my product page, would you check it again please, thank you very much

Comment: It's working fine, Please clear your cache, and try again

Comment: i am using default theme of magento and dont'n have my own theme, is it a problem

Comment: Yes it's the problem you need to create your own theme here is the link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: however i want to compile code in app/code/Myname/..., it just like an extension and really add new theme is unecessary, can you help me

Comment: File location of default Magento Luma theme  : www/yourprojectDir\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml add below code in body tag : <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="deliveryinfo.tab" as="deliveryinfo" template="product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Question</argument>
        </arguments>
        </block>
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: Good Solution work for me

Comment: Is there any way to change the order in which the tabs are rendered? For e.g. I want to show my tab before the "More Information" tab.

Comment: @V.S  Yes It's possible see here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122237/21339

Comment: @Arunendra Thanks for that. That removed all others (custom ones) but solved it by `$detailedInfoGroup = array_unique(array_merge($sortOrder, $newOrderTabbing))`.

Comment: How can I add more than one block in `catalog_product_view.xml`?

Comment: The best and simplest solution to implement! Works great. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Finally i got it:
In `catalog_product_view`:

```
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.question" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
              <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Question</argument>
              </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

And all I need is `attributes.php` file as the same as core folder in `Mymodule/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php`, copy all or replace some line of code if you want, change the namspace and you get it

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

**app\code\[NameSpace]\[ModuleName]\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Example\Examples\Block\[Blockname]" name="example.tab" template="Example_Examples::success.phtml" group="detailed_info">
              <arguments>
                  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Title</argument>
              </arguments>
          </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Using this you can create tab in product detail page like review tab

In your block file

```
public function getProduct(){
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setOrder('created_at')
                ->setPageSize(5);
    return  $collection;
}
```

You forget `getCollection()`

Comment: i follow your help and create a block, but nothing seem to work, i disable cache and it still nothing change, can you tell me more detail please

Comment: can you check var/log/system.xml file?

Comment: i checked it and nothing went wrong

Comment: can you show your block file?

Comment: my block file under Block/Question.php

Comment: @TrầnĐăngPhong check my updated answer

Comment: It works.But can you tell how i can sort order of the tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new tab on product detail page. I have already answer of this question, You can check my answer on "[My Custom product tab not displaying in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146229/my-custom-product-tab-not-displaying-in-magento-2/146483#146483)".