# My Custom product tab not displaying in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, tabs

I am trying to inject my custom product tab in storefront on product view page, but it's not displaying. For this I am written below code.

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_ProductTabs',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Test/ProductTabs/Block/CustomTab.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\ProductTabs\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class CustomTab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $_product = null;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->_product) {
            $this->_product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        }
        return $this->_product;
    }

}
```

**Test/ProductTabs/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_ProductTabs" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Test/ProductTabs/view/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
           <block class="Test\ProductTabs\Block\CustomTab" name="mycustom.tab" as="mycustom" template="Test_ProductTabs::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
               <arguments>
                   <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

**Test/ProductTabs/view/templates/kit.phtml**

```
<h1>Kit Components</h1>
```

above code is not working for me. Any help on this?

Comment: Your controller file?

Comment: @NitinPawar is it required?

Comment: Yes whenever i create the page i write controller for that page

Comment: @NitinPawar I think not required. I am creating storefront. any way how can i link up with tab to controller? can you share the code if it possible?

Comment: @NitinPawar any help on this?

Comment: I think for this you just need to override the product view template from the Magento_catalog module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48649/discussion-between-magento-two-and-nitin-pawar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in your layout file

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="mycustom.tab" as="mycustom" template="Test_ProductTabs::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>

</referenceBlock>
```

product related details all are available in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` so no need to create custom block for get product details.

**update**

wrong layout file location! it should be

`Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: not working....

Comment: wrong layout location see my updated answer

Comment: Yes I have wrongly created folder structure. I forgot it. Thanks you. Is there any way to display @ 1 tab as my custom tab?

Answer (score 3):

You code is fine just simple mistake you have done two mistake

please change file name

```
catalog_product_view_.xml
```

to

```
catalog_product_view.xml
```

change frontend layout and tempplate file location

```
Test/ProductTabs/view/layout/catalog_product_view_.xml
```

to

```
Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

change template file location

```
Test/ProductTabs/view/templates/kit.phtml
```

to

```
Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/templates/kit.phtml
```

Comment: that is typing mistake any way thanks bro...

Comment: Is there any way to display @ 1 tab as my custom tab?

Comment: @magentotwo refer link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110796/change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way to do this is to follow the same approach Magento uses to add the `description` attribute as one of the tabs on the product details page.

First create your attribute, lets say it's `tech_spec` and add it to whichever attribute sets you want it to so I can be updated from the Manage Manage Products page.

Then create/update your app\code[NameSpace][ModuleName]\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml file with:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.tech.spec" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getTechSpec</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">tech_spec</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">tech-spec</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Technical Specification</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

---

Alternatively if you don't want to add an attribute you can add a template instead.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.tech.spec" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/tech-spec.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Technical Specification</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code of layout:

```
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Test\ProductTabs\Block\CustomTab" name="customtab_display" template="template="Test_ProductTabs::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
   </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: remove /var and apply reindex and cache:flush

Comment: yes I executed above commands `cache:flush, cache:clean` and `indexer:reindex` but no luck.

Comment: may be you have issue in block so please remove `getProduct()`  then try again

Comment: Is there any way to display @ 1 tab as my custom tab?

Comment: for that you need to rewrite catalog view but here we are override that page

Answer (score 2):

1. First go to the admin panel of your Magento store and then navigate to 
   Stores -> Product. Click on Add New Attribute and create new Attribute. (Set Attribute label **DEMO** and Attribute code **demo**)
2. Now go to Stores -> Attribute Set and Add Attribute Set.
3. Now click on your Attribute Set and dragged unassigned Attribute  (which you have created in first step) to Product Details and click Save.
4. Now go to your product edit page in admin panel and change the attribute name and template name which you have created in first and second step.
5. In **app/code/Test/ProductTabs/etc/module.xml** paste this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Test_ProductTabs" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

5. In **app/code/Test/ProductTabs/registration.php**, paste this code.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_ProductTabs',
    __DIR__
);
```

6. In **app/code/Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**, paste this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="demo.tab" template="Test_ProductTabs::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

7. Now in **app/code/Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/templates/custom_tab.phtml**, paste this code.

```
<?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>
 <h1 style="color: #00aeed"><?php echo $product->getData('demo'); ?></h1>
```

8. Now lauch your product page.

Comment: Create a whole module just to call `echo $product->getData('demo');` in a custom template file? It seems easier to extend `catalog_product_view.xml` in the Theme - either by re-using the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description` block as described by @Holly, or even by adding your custom `custom_tab.phtml` to the theme.

Comment: Nicely explain and helpful

Answer (score 2):

I add my discoveries as a new answer so it has better visibility and can be up-voted.
Indeed there was some files naming / folder structure mistakes. But this is not enough...

**TL;DR :**

- Add a `sort_order` value to your tab block : `<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">99</argument>`
- Be sure this `sort_order` value is UNIQUE among other tabs
- Execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and `php bin/magento cache:clear`

**Reasons why :**

Everything takes place in `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details::getGroupSortedChildNames()`

- If you want your tab to be pulled by `getGroupChildNames()` you need to **reindex** before (`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`)
- `getGroupSortedChildNames()` method performs a tab sorting using blocks' `sort_order` values. If no `sort_order` is found, fallback is `0`. If more than one tab blocks are defined without `sort_order`, the last one to be given `0` will replace all previous tabs in final sorted tabs array. In my case, last one was a tab from Mageplaza_Faq module...

I hope this will prevent other people to pull their hair for a couple of hours like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the steps to create a custom tab. And tab is shown. Now the tab is shown on every product page.
Even if the attribute is not on the attribute set.

the '**custom_tab**' is on '**Un**assigned Attributes' for '**default**' attribute set.

the '**custom_tab**' is on 'Assigned attributes' for '**att_set1**' attribute set.

the '**custom_tab**' is on '**Un**assigned Attributes' for '**att_set2**' attribute set

still the '**custom tab**' is shown on all product pages?

do I need to change anything else?

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Please consider leaving a comment or ask a new question.

Comment: ok, I could not commend because I did not have enough reputations.