# How to show/hide custom tab in Product page from Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, catalog, tabs

I have created a custom tab and which is working and showing fine on the product page. Here how can I show/hide the custom tab based on product type (`simple`, `bundle` etc...).

**my code is**

**Block**

```
<?php
namespace Test\CustomCart\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class CustomTab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $_product = null;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->_product) {
            $this->_product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        }
        return $this->_product;
    }


}
```

**view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Test\CustomCart\Block\CustomTab" name="mycustom.tab" as="mycustom" template="Test_CustomCart::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**/view/frontend/templates/kit.phtml**

```
<h1>Hey I'm here!!!</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show tab in simple product create `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml` file add your code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Test\CustomCart\Block\CustomTab" name="mycustom.tab" as="mycustom" template="Test_CustomCart::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you want to display tab in bundle product add code in `catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
             <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <block class="Test\CustomCart\Block\CustomTab" name="mycustom.tab" as="mycustom" template="Test_CustomCart::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your layout xml :

```
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Test\CustomCart\Block\CustomTab" name="mycustom.tab"" template="Test_CustomCart::kit.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
```

After that please remove/flush cache and reindex then check.

Comment: where is the logic? is it enough?

Comment: yes try this. It works

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use Attribute set.

In your product edit page, set the custom tab attribute only on those products in which you wants to display Customer tab on product detail page.

You can also check my answer on ["My Custom product tab not displaying in Magento 2"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146229/my-custom-product-tab-not-displaying-in-magento-2/146483#146483).