# Magento 2: Product page compare product add in new tab

Tags: magento2.3, product-page, compare

I am using `magento 2.3.3` in custom theme and I want to compare products add in new tab
how can achieve this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On Product Detail Page, First Create a new tab and add below code in xml.
In your theme/module's `catalog_product_view.xml` if you want to create a new phtml in new tab use below code

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.question" template="product/view/yournewphtmlfile.phtml" group="detailed_info">
              <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Question</argument>
              </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Or to move content add below code to add compare products to details tab.

```
<move element="category.product.addto.compare" destination="product.question" />
```

Comment: can you provide me here full code? because if i will create tab and what name given of tab and how to add code

Comment: thank you for your answer but here you have defined block class name in module name and template but i am not using custom module i want to compare product transfer in new tab

Comment: refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106299/add-new-tab-on-product-detail-page-magento-2   2.) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146229/my-custom-product-tab-not-displaying-in-magento-2/146483#146483

Comment: @MohitPatel i need compare product move on new tab