# Magento 2: Create extra tab with info on product detail page

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm struggling with a Magento 2 issue here. With Venustheme Cropshop installed I'm trying to add an extra tab with listed info to de product detail page. Please check the below image:

[image]
I already saw [Trần Đăng Phong's question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106299/add-new-tab-on-product-detail-page-magento-2), but that one is solved with code. It seems more logical to fix it within the admin. That SHOULD be possible right?

I managed to add a list of attributes (Fats, Carbs, etc.) in an attribute set (Nutritionfacts), but it pops-up under the "more info"-tab. I'd like this info to show in a new tab "Nutrition facts".

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I don't think there are any methods to add product tab without coding. But I think it's good to be a feature in future.

Answer (score 3):

To add an extra tab you need to do some coding

for example I am adding **delivery** tab

To edit and update catalog_product_view.xml go to below location

`app\design\frontend\vendorname\themename\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

if file is not here the override with

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Now Add below code for adding delivery tab

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.delivery" as="features" template="product/view/delivery.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Delivery</argument>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Place **delivery.phtml** file under

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/delivery.phtml
```

To add content via admin block **create a block delivery-tab** and use below code in delivery.phtml file

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('delivery-tab')->toHtml();?>
```

I hope this will solve your problem. If don't see any change then please run , upgrade, deploy and cache commands after this

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for me. Creating a block wouldn't solve my problem. Instead, I'd like to show an attribute of the corresponding product.

Comment: okay, please update your question to get the right help

Answer (score 0):

just want to know if you get successful and if you got the nutritional facts with a css design to looks like a US label.

Regards, Andre