# Adding Custom tabs along with description

Tags: magento2.3.2

i am facing problems while adding a custom tab on the PDP page along with the description.

**what i have tried**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="tabbb.tab" template="Learning_Module::shipping.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Shipping Policy</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>


<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="ssssss" template="Learning_Module::delivery.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Delivery</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>

</body>
</page>
```

**shipping.phtml**

```
<?php

$product = $block->getProduct();

?>
dxsdccdcsdc
<!--<h1 style="color: #ff6e17"><?php echo $product->getData('tabbb'); ?></h1>-->
```

**delivery.phtml**

```
<?php

$product = $block->getProduct();

?>
sdcfcd
<!--<h1 style="color: #ff6e17"><?php echo $product->getData('sssss'); ?></h1>-->
```

afterall, this all am getting is only a single whereas the second tab is missing. prefer the image fro more details
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new tab on product detail page Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106299/add-new-tab-on-product-detail-page-magento-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your XML file content with this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom-tab-1" template="Learning_Module::shipping.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Shipping Policy</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom-tab-2" template="Learning_Module::delivery.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Delivery</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">60</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to add `sort_order` for new tabs. After changing above file please run below commands.

```
php bin/magento c:c full_page layout
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: ok give me a min let me try

Comment: it works could you please expalin what is the use of sort order here

Comment: Sure, If you'll not add sort number to tabs then it will take **0** as a sort number by default and you have created 2 tabs in both tabs that will take 0 so you can see only last tab. If you'll remove last then you can second tab. that logic is available here in this default Magento file **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Details.php**

Comment: ok that means it is overriding my first tab based on sort order

Comment: Yes, Right. If you will not add sort order then all 0 sort order tabs will override on previous tabs.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help then. Otherwise please accept my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: thank you and i have already accepted your ans

Comment: Thanks again... :)