# How to move reviews tab to the last in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, review

I have a problem moving this reviews tab to the last. Sorry I'm new to magento 2. I did all my best searching the web for solutions. but I was hoping someone can help me here.

[image]

Comment: refer this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122237/36463

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer in the link you've provided. It did the trick. Now the Reviews tab is in the last order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just change inside **`details.phtml`** template file and set as per your requirement tabbing order,

set details.phtml file inside your theme folder,

```
app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

first print order of tabbing by,

```
   <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):
                echo "<pre>";print_r($detailedInfoGroup);
    ?>

            **Now you have display your order tabbing in array.
            you can just change your order by creating new array,**

 <?php $newOrderTabbing = array('product.info.description','product.attributes','reviews.tab'); //custom add ?>
```

Inside foreach in this file, rename array name like   instead of  
Code for details.phtml file,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <?php $newOrderTabbing = array('product.info.description','reviews.tab','product.attributes'); //custom add ?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($newOrderTabbing as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After adding above code now review tab display at the end of tab.
Finally Tab orders are display like `Details, More Information,Review`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract reviews.tab from  detailedInfoGroup array and push after

```
if (($key = array_search('reviews.tab', $detailedInfoGroup)) !== false) {
    unset($detailedInfoGroup[$key]);
    array_push($detailedInfoGroup, "reviews.tab");
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, working fine

Answer (score 1):

This is working. We can use sort order to move the tab where we want.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">70</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento 2.1 CE**

Inside:

`app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml`

or:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml`

Add:

```
<?php 
  $customTabsLayout = array_diff($detailedInfoGroup, ['reviews.tab','product.attributes']);
  $toAddAafter = array('product.attributes','reviews.tab');
  $newOrderTabbing = array_merge($customTabsLayout,$toAddAafter);
?>
```

and change

```
<?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach ($newOrderTabbing as $name):?>
```

Like

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>

<?php 
  $customTabsLayout = array_diff($detailedInfoGroup, ['reviews.tab','product.attributes']);
  $toAddAafter = array('product.attributes','reviews.tab');
  $newOrderTabbing = array_merge($customTabsLayout,$toAddAafter);
?>

    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($newOrderTabbing as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Try not to repeat the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

Modify the order of the xml blocks in `catalog_product_view.xml`. They should all be listed in the `name="product.info.details"` xml node

Comment: how? can you show how to do it?